# Scrape live updating value from HTML in R

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape values from a page such as this: https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/CBX22/options/nov-22 in R, currently using `rvest`. Specifically, I want the current price and implied volatility. Using the SelectorGadget tool, I was able to find the nodes needed for these values.

Using the following, I was able to get the implied volatility:

```
library(rvest)

html <- read_html("https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/CBX22/options/nov-22")
html_text(html_nodes(html, '.text-medium-up-center strong'))

[1] "43.92%"
```

However, it seems the current price can't be scraped in the same way since it is a value that updates every few seconds without needing to refresh the page. Using the same process as with the implied volatility, except subbing in the node for price,

```
html_text(html_nodes(html, '.pricechangerow > .last-change'))
```

yields

```
[1] "[[ item.lastPrice ]]"     "[[ rootItem.lastPrice ]]"
```

Is there a way to retrieve whatever the last price happened to be at the time the html is read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you are looking for is stored in a json string at the bottom of the html and is only written to the relevant html element by javascript in your browser after the page has loaded. `rvest` won't change any of the html elements - it simply reads the html that is on the page as-is.

To extract the value, you need to parse the json and obtain the correct element from the resulting nested list:

```r
read_html("https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/CBX22/options/nov-22") %>%
  html_element(xpath = '//script[@id="bc-dynamic-config"]') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  jsonlite::parse_json() %>%
  getElement('currentSymbol') %>%
  getElement('lastPrice')
#> [1] "90.37"
```

If I run the same code a few seconds later (equivalent to refereshing the page in your browser), I get:

```r
read_html("https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/CBX22/options/nov-22") %>%
  html_element(xpath = '//script[@id="bc-dynamic-config"]') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  jsonlite::parse_json() %>%
  getElement('currentSymbol') %>%
  getElement('lastPrice')
#> [1] "90.47"
```